# GMail AUTH LOGIN SMTP Authentication

Tags: smtp, gmail

I'm trying to authenticate myself against GMail SMTP Server by using the LOGIN authentication mechanism. AUTH LOGIN is advertised as supported in the response to the EHLO command, but when I'm trying to send AUTH LOGIN to the server, I'm getting "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized Authentication Type" response. Here is the dialog between the server and the client:

```
S: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP d9sm13589149wiy.2
C: EHLO client
S: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
S: 250-SIZE 35882577
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
s: 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
C: AUTH LOGIN
S: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized Authentication Type d9sm13589149wiy.2
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What's your source for the correctness?  I don't see AUTH LOGIN ever becoming an RFC proper, only a draft from Cyrus(?) and an extension specification from Microsoft.  (Microsoft adds the AUTH LOGIN username functionality that you're noting.)  It certainly sounds like Google should support AUTH LOGIN (with no username) but it looks less clear cut than one would have expected.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - Well, that RFC draft from Cyrus was the only reference I've seen on LOGIN authentication. I assume by this Microsoft Extension you mean [MS-XLOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433484(v=exchg.80).aspx). If yes, than that perfectly answers my question!

Comment: yeah, but my reading of the Microsoft document makes it pretty clear that gmail should support "AUTH LOGIN" as well as "AUTH LOGIN username".

Comment: @EdwardThomson - This is also what I would expect. But if I try AUTH LOGIN via Telnet, gmail rejects the command with "504 Unrecognized Authentication Type". And because of the TLS I cannot see what is really happening between Outlook and gmail MTA.

Comment: As of Jan 2012, AUTH LOGIN works as expected.  Google's servers respond with 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6.  Once the username is given (base64 encoded), it then responds with 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6.  If the correct password is given (also base64 encoded), it responds with 235 2.7.0 Accepted.  So maybe that was a temporary programming error you were experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've found out is that once I'm using "AUTH LOGIN base64username", which is not really how LOGIN should be working, it actually seems to work:

```
S: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP n3sm42168657wiz.9
C: EHLO client
S: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [x.x.x.x]
S: 250-SIZE 35882577
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
S: 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
C: AUTH LOGIN base64username
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: base64password
S: 235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

Answer (score 1):

Use STARTTLS first, negociate a security exchange SSL or TLS, then recall EHLO and then you can , i guess, use the PLAIN and LOGIN machanisms